# QEMU (with virtmanager) boots to uefi shell when trying to install windows 11

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, uefi, qemu

I'm trying to make a windows 11 qemu VM on my arch linux install but when I start it it shows:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G50ON.png)
what can I do to make it boot normally into the windows installer with UEFI and secure boot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It has to use UEFI for Windows 11. Not much other way

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I believe I had let the "Press any key to boot from.." screen timeout. I reboot the VM, and pressed a key when prompted, and it worked fine. This is corroborated by [FAQ](https://thatsniceguy.gitbook.io/utmfaq/most-asked-questions#why-do-i-get-an-efi-shell-when-booting-windows-10) someone mentioned on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I typed `exit` at the UEFI shell and it went to the "Press any key to boot from" screen and it worked for me.